# Div with list scroller inside with scroll buttons

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list that I need to have inside a div and have 2 buttons to scroll left and right.

I need it to hide the overflow.

Can anyone put me in the right direction as I don't know what to google for?

Here's my initial code:

```
<ul id="box-wrapper">
<li>    
    <div class="box">
        Box 1
    </div>
</li>  
<li>    
    <div class="box">
        Box 2
    </div>
</li> 
<li>    
    <div class="box">
        Box 3
    </div>
</li> 
<li>    
    <div class="box">
        Box 4
    </div>
</li> 
<li>    
    <div class="box">
        Box 5
    </div>
</li>      
</ul>
<div class="scroll-left">Left Button</div>
<div class="scroll-right">Left Button</div>
```

Here's an image with what I need:

[image]

Comment: heres an upvote, now you can post pictures :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/7daffjh8/8/

html

```
<ul id="box-wrapper">
    <li>Box 1</li>
    <li>Box 2</li>
    <li>Box 3</li>
    <li>Box 4</li>
    <li>Box 5</li>
</ul>
<button class="scroll-left">Left Button</button>
<button class="scroll-right">right Button</button>
```

css

```
ul {
    height:210px;
    display:block;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    margin:5px;
}
```

js

```
var scrolled = 0;
$(".scroll-left").on("click" ,function(){
    scrolled=scrolled-300;
    $("ul").animate({
        scrollLeft:  scrolled
    });
});
$(".scroll-right").on("click" ,function(){
    scrolled=scrolled+300;
    $("ul").animate({
        scrollLeft:  scrolled
    });
});
```

Comment: When the list is bigger than the list this will show a scrollbar. I want it to hide instead but to be available through the scroll left or right buttons

Comment: ill put together a fiddle for you

Comment: I've managed to add an image now, so i shows what I'm after. thanks